# conda commands do not work under Mac OS X 10.5.3

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a problem as seen at [Missing or syntactical error for styles in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476644/missing-or-syntactical-error-for-styles-in-matplotlib?noredirect=1#comment106989698_60476644), and the suggestion was that I had a corrupted install of python library.

I tried a complete uninstall and reinstall of anaconda, and now none of the `conda` commands work.I have no idea how to diagnose this problem, and I fear I'm going to go to the lengths  I did in the above thread, destroying things.

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently a known bug with Catalina on OS X. I had to add the conda binaries to my PATH variable and all was well.